# Which one is better for website design, photoshop or illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, website-templates

Need suggestions, which adobe program is better for website mock-up design. I am using Photoshop throughout of my career. But adobe community is talking about illustrator cc for website mock-up design.I just want to know your(web designers) preference.

Comment: It doesn't matter... whatever works *for you*.

Comment: Neither. Photoshop and Illustrator are both graphics programs, not web design programs. If you want to stick to the Creative Suite, Dreamweaver is the web design program.

Comment: I mean Website mock-up designs.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would highly advise anyone to run away from dreamweaver as far as they can. It promotes bad coding habits.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 I was under the impression (though not from personal use, only hearsay) that it had improved vastly in that respect over the past five or so years. I’ve never used it myself; I only mentioned it as the option _within the Creative Suite_.

Comment: Dreamweaver in **code view** is fine. Dreamweaver in **layout view** is a problem, but layout view is often used by those who may not actually understand HTML/CSS so they don't know to check the code view.

Comment: Illustrator uses vector which will make your website a lot lighter and load a lot faster. It's not just a personal preference issue. There's pros and cons to both. Really you should use both at the same time to get the advantages of both and also dreamweaver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, this question is asking a large group of individuals to provide a concrete answer on a topic that relies heavily on an individuals personal preference, application skill set and workflow efficiency. All of those factors can vary drastically from artist to artist.

In a nut shell Metis already answered your question, the same result can be achieved in either Photoshop or Illustrator. Realistically, it comes down to which program you are most comfortable and efficient with while simultaneously knowing and understanding the essential design requirements of the project.

Comment: thanks for answer. Can you please upvote my question ?, in this way it will useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

Try **Sketch** (Bohemian Coding) 
it's the current top software for designing websites, apps and interfaces 
it is based on CSS and have many plugins available, some of them allowing for export to HTML.

However, Sketch is a Mac only product and they have stated that they have no intention of ever providing a Unix or Windows product.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create mockups with interaction you can also try Adobe Experience Design, it's a new tool for rapid prototyping:

> Go from idea to prototype faster with Experience Design CC (Beta), the
>   first all-in-one cross-platform tool for designing and prototyping
>   websites and mobile apps.

http://www.adobe.com/products/experience-design.html

It's still in Beta but pretty easy to work with.

Comment: Thanks for update. Can you please upvote my question, in this way it will useful for others